# How to format a JSON String in Swift?

Tags: json, swift

I have a JSON String that follows a format like `{ name: "John" }` and not `{ "name" : "John"}` and that is resulting in a nil whenever I try to access the name key because:

`Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No string key for value in object around character 1."`

I am looking for a function that fixes/parses/formats this JSON file into something readable? How do sites like [JSON Format](http://jsonformat.com/#jsondataurllabel) do it?

Comment: You could first blame the string creator ;-)

Comment: is the JSON String just in a variable of type String?

Comment: @OlivierWilkinson Yes, it's a variable of type string.

Comment: check this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15265780/291240

Comment: @WilliamHu I checked it before. I cannot copy paste the validated string from sites like JSON Lint, I need to convert that string into something readable/valid through a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny enough, `{ name: "John" }` makes a valid JSON object in Javascript. So your problem now becomes finding a Javascript intepreter for Swift!

There's one built-in to recent versions of Mac OS X and iOS: `WKWebView`. It's a web rendering engine with a Javascript parser. Link your target with WebKit and try this:

```
import WebKit

class MyJSONParser {
    private static let webView = WKWebView()

    class func parse(jsonString: String, completionHandler: (AnyObject?, NSError?) -> Void) {
        self.webView.evaluateJavaScript(jsonString, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let str = "{ firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith' }"

// You must assign the JSON string to a variable or the Javascript
// will return void. Note that this runs asynchronously
MyJSONParser.parse("tmp = \(str)") { result, error in
    guard error == nil else {
        print(error)
        return
    }
    if let dict = result as? [String: String] {
        print(dict)
    } else {
       print("Can't convert to Dictionary")
    }
}
```

### Swift 3

```
import WebKit
class MyJSONParser {
    private static let webView = WKWebView()

    class func parse(jsonString: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Any?, Error?) -> Void) {
        self.webView.evaluateJavaScript(jsonString, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}

let str = "{ firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith' }"

// You must assign the JSON string to a variable or the Javascript
// will return void. Note that this runs asynchronously
MyJSONParser.parse(jsonString: "tmp = \(str)") { result, error in
    guard error == nil else {
        print(error!)
        return
    }
    if let dict = result as? [String: String] {
        print(dict)
    } else {
        print("Can't convert to Dictionary")
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing prints out when I try it in Playground. Here's the [screenshot](http://imgur.com/rHvHunk).